# Backing up saves to computer (while subscribed to PS+)

Tags: psn, ps-vita, playstation-plus

After much searching, I managed to find my saves in the Content Manager, but only under "Online Storage" (PS+). The heading for `PS Vita System → Online Storage` is "Saved Data (PS Vita)".
[image: PS Vita System → Online Storage]
[image: Saved Data (PS Vita)]

When attempting `PS Vita System → PC`, the only "Saved Data" options are "PSP/Other" and "PlayStation" (no "Saved Data (PS Vita)" option).
[image: PS Vita System → PC]

Is this because PS+ online backups override this setting? Do I need to disconnect my PSN account in order to move the saves to my computer? Or is this setting not normally available in the PC menu anyway? How can I back up these saves?

Answer (score 1):

You could never back up Vita game saves to PC, you can only copy the applications themselves, this includes the save data. To do so, choose *PS Vita* under *Applications*
[image: PS Vita -> PC menu]

You'll then have the option to pick games to copy to your PC
[image: Choosing Applications to copy to PC]